# How to enable scroll bar in an eclipse table

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I created a table with many rows. when i run this it is displaying all the rows in one big window. how should i limit the no of rows that are displayed in a table and have a vertical scroll bar to view the other rows.

i tried with calling setBounds and setSize on the table. But it is still showing all the rows in one big window.

```
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
        Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
        table.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
             TableColumn column = new TableColumn (table, SWT.NONE);
             column.setText ("Column " + i);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
             table.getColumn(i).setWidth(150);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            TableItem item = new TableItem(table,SWT.NONE);
            item.setText(new String[]{"Item " + i,"Item " + i,"Item " + i,"Item " + i});
        }
        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
          if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
table.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.swtDefault().hint(100, 100).create());
```

You can't set the dimension of your table with `setBounds()` because it is the layout of the `Composite` containing the table that sets the position and dimension of the table. Look at following link for useful information on SWT layouts: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html

Comment: is it possible to do it using the griddata method. something like table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true))

Comment: @vjk You can create `new GridData()`, specify a height and width with `heightInt` and `widthInt`, and attach it to the `Table`. It's equivalent to my answer (`GridDataFactory` allow me to do it in a single line).

Comment: Thanks for the useful link about swt layouts